# How can I deploy to cloudcontrol a python app that requires pysqlite?

Tags: python, pysqlite, cloudcontrol

I have a python web app that depends on the `pysqlite` module but pushing it to cloudcontrol fails with error

`remote:            src/connection.h:33:21: fatal error: sqlite3.h: No such file or directory`

Is there any way to get that app running on cloudcontrol or is it a lost cause for now ?

Comment: Sqlite is not part of the stack, because a file system based database is not very useful given the non ephemeral file system. Depending on what you're doing it might be better to use one of the databases provided in the Add-on market.

Comment: I understand that. But in my case I need sqlite to use a in-memory database to run tests. I do not care about persisting any data

Comment: Depending on what you're trying to build a custom buildpack that provides sqlite might be the way to go here. Can you share a little bit more about your use case? That would help me understand if it's something that we should fix because it's useful to a lot of customers or if it's a very special case.

Comment: it is to host http://b3-censor-test.cucurb.net/ - source code at https://github.com/thomasleveil/b3-censor-test.

The website page will run the `b3` module from https://github.com/BigBrotherBot/big-brother-bot in test mode which implies using sqlite ':memory:' database instead of MySQL